# Java Socket Data only sends when close *not* called

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am running an android app in an emulator with android studio and port forwarding port 8080 on the device to port 8080 on my machine using `adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080`.

I am listening to port 8080 on my machine and printing the incoming data using `nc -kl localhost 8080`.

I am running the code below through an android app on it's own thread. I only see data throughput when the socket is *not* closed. Of course when I try to open up a connection on the same port, it is refused because the previous connection is still open. What am I doing wrong?

```
try {
    final Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));

    // I've tried setting these
    // socket.setSoLinger(true, 1);
    // socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

    socket.getOutputStream().write(new byte[]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}, 0, 5);
    socket.getOutputStream().flush();

    // Data is only received when this is commented out
    // socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "It is refused because the previous connection is still open" is not correct. You can open a large number of connections to "localhost:8080". What happens at the server when you close this socket?

Comment: I was mistaken in my understanding of sockets. On the server, the connection is closed. I created a small python server to listen to the socket connection. It would print on socket connection and disconnect as well as any data that would pass through. With socket.close() present, it would print connect/disconnect but no data. Without socket.close() it would print connect and the data but not disconnect. Any further calls (pressing the button multiple times) resulted in no further prints.

Comment: By adding a Thread.sleep(1) after the flush operation, the data was printed and the socket was successfully closed. This is a hacky solution and I am displeased with it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't make head or tail of that, but obviously there is something wrong with your Python code. Nothing wrong above.

Comment: Perhaps, but if my original post I didn't use python. I used the nc tool. Both had equivalent results. Perhaps there is some timing issue with the android emulator?